# Proguard folder empty, android

Tags: java, android, directory, proguard

I enabled proguard using the txt file but it generated an empty proguard folder without the txt files, whats wrong? i checked the workspace and it was empty there too.

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt
# Project target.
target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7
```

Comment: Proguard works when you do the final signed apk export, if you simply compile your project it doesn't run at all

Comment: I exported it, but it didn't create the txt files in the proguard folder